# Display data based on data in a different table, using a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have multiple tables, one has the columns ID/Member/Type/UseDefault.
The other table has columns with descriptive information about a person, based on the ID.

Type will mostly be defualt. In which case, the information that corresponds with ID is perfectly fine. If UseDefault is false (which will only happen when type IS NOT defualt AND they do not want to use the default value), then the supplied ID is also perfectly suitable. However, if type is not default, but use default is entered as Yes, i need to display the information that is associated with the same member's default ID.

For example:
Example

```
ID  Member  Type   UseDefault

  1   joe    default    Y
  2   joe    additional Y 
  3   joe    third      N
```

As you can see...for row 1, use Default is Yes, but the type is already default.

In row 3, use default is No, so you continue with ID 3.

However in row 2. Use default is yes, and the type is not default, so we need to find the row that is Joe's default type. Here is the other table, and the expected output from my query.

Info

```
ID   Car     Color  Food

  1  Benz    Red    Pizza
  2  Ferrari Green  Cheese
  3  Minivan Orange Hamburger

expected output:

Output

ID    Car     Color  Food

  1   Benz    Red    Pizza
  1   Benz    Red    Pizza
  3   Minivan Orange Hamburger
```

basically i have

```
declare
id varchar2(2000)

Select I.Car, I.Color, I.FavoriteFood
from Info I 
full outer join Example e on e.id = i.id
where case id:= when (e.useDefault = 'N' AND e.Type <> 'Default') then (select id from example where e.name = name and e.type = default) else e.type end
and i.id = @id;
```

Comment: Is 'joe' as member identifier a unique identifier for members? Otherwise how do you know which 'joe' rows are related to each other, and which are from different Joe's?

Comment: there would be other names, the only reason i included that part is because there will be a steve with a default and a james with a default as well as other values

Comment: You didn't understand my question. Will there be a Joe Brown and a Joe Hill? How do you know which id's (multiple!) go with which joe? Do you also have another column for member_id, to distinguish one Joe from the other?

Comment: Can you also confirm which database you are using?  The code you posted does not suggest Oracle as you've tagged. Where did you get the code from?  Did you actually try it?

Comment: Please edit your post so the columns line up with the data, and lose the `/` and `-` characters if they aren't doing anything. It's hard to follow what your data is. Also as others have mentioned, `@id` and `then set` aren't valid in Oracle, and I don't see any PL/SQL.

Comment: it is oracle, ultimately oracle, though i was testing it on ssms at home (dont have oracle on the personal computer).

@mathguy, only 1 joe.

Comment: `@id varchar(2000)` is most definitely **not** Oracle PL/SQL. And `case @id when e.useDefault = 'N' ..` is wrong as well. If you use a "searched case" using `case x ...` then you can't have expressions in the `when` parts. It's either `case x when 1 then .. when 2 then ... end` **or** `case when x = 1 then .. when x = 2 then ... end`

Comment: see my edits please

Comment: Does every "member" have a "default" row in the first table? If not, what should be the result when "usedefault" is YES but there is no default - just disregard the "usedefault"? Also, do you really want a FULL outer join?

Comment: i dont think i want a full outer join, it just seemed like the best way to accomplish...and yes every member will have exactly 1 default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with
     inputs ( id, member, type, usedefault ) as (
       select 1, 'joe', 'default'   , 'Y' from dual union all
       select 2, 'joe', 'additional', 'Y' from dual union all
       select 3, 'joe', 'third'     , 'N' from dual
     ),
     info ( id, car, color, food ) as (
       select 1, 'Benz'   , 'Red'   , 'Pizza'     from dual union all
       select 2, 'Ferrari', 'Green' , 'Cheese'    from dual union all
       select 3, 'Minivan', 'Orange', 'Hamburger' from dual
     ),
     defaults ( id, member ) as (
       select id, member
       from   inputs
       where  type = 'default'
     ),
     prep ( id_to_use ) as (
       select case when i.usedefault = 'N' then i.id
                   else d.id end   as id_to_use
       from   inputs i inner join defaults d on i.member = d.member
     )
select p.id_to_use as id, i.car, i.color, i.food
from   prep p left outer join info i on p.id_to_use = i.id
;
```